# how can i learn my client ip with .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, network-programming

i need my client ip from whatismyip.com. But Regex pattern is not correct i think? Can you help me this patttern?

Comment: Why are you using whatismyip.com to retrieve your ip? :)

Comment: Voting to close. Don't ask the same question twice. If your question does not get you the answer, try expanding it with more detail. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272483/how-can-i-get-ip-address-of-my-3g-modem

Comment: For what it's worth, I believe my answer to your original question should do the trick: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272483/how-can-i-get-ip-address-of-my-3g-modem/2272673#2272673

Comment: Yes, Jørns answer to the original question is entirely sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved way easier using the automation interface from www.whatismyip.com, so there's no need for any regex:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string url = "http://www.whatismyip.com/automation/n09230945.asp";

        var client = new WebClient();
        try
        {
            var myIp = client.DownloadString(url);
            Console.WriteLine("Your IP: " + myIp);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error contacting website: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you read the comment in the obtained HTML:

> Please set your code to scrape
>   your IP from
>   www.whatismyip.com/automation/n09230945.asp
>   For more info, please see our
>   "Recommended Automation Practices"
>   thread in the Forum.

So this should get you going:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    Console.WriteLine(client.DownloadString(
        "http://www.whatismyip.com/automation/n09230945.asp"));
}
```

Comment: using is a good technique to automatically delete the resource used by variable..

Answer (score 0):

Try to use 
http://www.whatismyip.org/ 
It's much simpler.

Or you want to parse information exactly whatismyip.com?

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this instead:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string whatIsMyIp = "http://www.whatismyip.com/automation/n09230945.asp";
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();
        string requestHtml = "";
        try
        {
            requestHtml = utf8.GetString(wc.DownloadData(whatIsMyIp));
        }
        catch (WebException we)
        {
            // do something with exception 
            Console.Write(we.ToString());
        }

        IPAddress externalIp = null;
        externalIp = IPAddress.Parse(requestHtml);

        Console.Write("IP Numaram:" + externalIp.ToString());
        Console.ReadKey(); 

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you get the ip in ASP.NET C#

```
string pstrClientAddress = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
```